# Questions about the unit of the data

Tags: dolphindb

For advice, when using DolpinDB to read the IoT data such as the ambient temperature (℃), atmospheric pressure (kPa), motor current (A), generator power (kW), water pressure (MPa), etc. The units of them are different.

Question: How to mark the units of different data in a table? For example, in an Excel table, I can have two rows to record them, the "label name" are recorded in the first row, and the units are recorded in the second row, then the data is recorded in the rows starting from the third row. How to create such a table in DolphinDB?
Or is it necessary to build another table to save the units. In this table the units and the labels are in one-to-one correspondence.

Answer (score 0):

If it is stock financial data, these data have no units. But the unit of IOT data is still critical. When visualizing, in addition to displaying the value, you must also bring the corresponding unit. In addition, you must also determine the unit when calculating. For example, when calculating power, power = current x voltage. Different current and voltage units have different power units calculated.